# Java Foreach Loop through Hashmap Throwing NPE -- What might the problem here be?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, iteration

As part of a project, I've been tasked with creating a method that outputs a List of the most commonly occurring Strings in a given input List. The assignment specifies that this must be done by creating a hashmap of words (Strings) and the number of times they appear (Integers.) Then, the ones that appear most often must be returned in a List.

When I tried to run my implementation of this, I got the following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.util.Iterator.next()" is null`

```
public SList commonStrings() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>(this.size());
        int numOfMostCommon = 0;
        int highest = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            if (frequencies.containsKey(this.backingArray[i])) {
                frequencies.replace(this.backingArray[i], frequencies.get(backingArray[i]+1));
            }
            else {
                frequencies.put(this.backingArray[i], 1);
            }
        }
        for (int i : frequencies.values()) {
           if (i > highest) {
                highest = i;
            }
        }
        for (int i : frequencies.values()) {
           if (i == highest) {
                numOfMostCommon++;
            }
        }
        String[] mostCommon = new String[numOfMostCommon];
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> i : frequencies.entrySet()) {
            if (i.getValue() == highest) {
                mostCommon[j] = i.getKey();
                j++;
            }
        }
        return new SListArray(mostCommon);
        }
```

Comment: You have a typo: `frequencies.get(backingArray[i]+1)` is not the same as `frequencies.get(backingArray[i])+1`.

Comment: `frequencies.get(backingArray[i]+1)` is wrong. It should be `frequencies.get(backingArray[i])+1` (note the different place of the `)`). But don’t make it so complicated. Assuming `this.size()` returns `backingArray.length`, use `for(int value: backingArray) frequencies.merge(value, 1, Integer::sum);` Further, you can use `int highest = Collections.max(frequencies.values()), numOfMostCommon = Collections.frequency(frequencies.values(), highest);`

Comment: An alternative to the last loop: `int highest = Collections.max(frequencies.values()); frequencies.values().removeIf(freq -> freq != highest); String[] mostCommon = frequencies.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo. You wrote:

```
frequencies.get(backingArray[i]+1)
```

You wanted:

```
frequencies.get(backingArray[i])+1
```

The former gets the value associated with something else, which is likely non-existent, thus, gets you `null`, thus, replaces the value associated with `backingArray[i]` with `null`. Which you later get, resulting in a NullpointerException`.

The second form simply 'adds 1 to the value' which is presumably what you want.

Note that you can do this in a single operation with `merge`, but, that's not going to meaningfully change any performance here - it would just be arguably easier to read.